# Should we burninate C tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we delete the C tag?  Coding questions are off-topic here, so the C tag is a "broken window" that might be misleading posters into thinking it's OK to post a coding question or post their C source code.

Looking through [the questions tagged C](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), most of them are bad questions that aren't not appropriate here.  The majority are closed.  I count only three questions with the [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag that are not problematic:

- [Is the Syntax of C Language completely defined by CFGs?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16426/755)
- [Why do negative array indices make sense?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10837/755)
- [Find the index of minimum number that is greater than key given of a sorted array, does these two functions return same result?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/45349/755)

All of these would be fine without the [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag; they have other tags that are fine.  Also, the third question doesn't have anything to do with C, so a C tag is useless here (the only relationship is that the poster included some C source code; however, our policy says people aren't supposed to do that -- they're supposed to use pseudocode -- so losing the C tag from the third question will be no loss).

The potential benefit is that maybe it eliminates one signpost that might be misleading posters.  I have no idea whether it will actually help or not, but it's something we could try.

Earlier, I tried writing a [tag wiki excerpt](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/c/info) stating very clearly that programming questions are off-topic here, but it doesn't seem to have solved the problem, hence my question about deletion.

So, should we delete the C tag?  (i.e., remove it from every question currently tagged [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c), and let the tag be auto-deleted)  Should we blacklist it?

Comment: I seem to remember discussion this, and Gilles (?) answer was: keep the tag(s) to avoid confusion a) for the odd question for which the tag is appropriate, and b) for new posters (which may otherwise use *any* tag). Also, [tag:c] or [tag:java] are kind of useful "Dear Mod, please look at me" triggers.

Comment: I also once raised the same question in the chat. I think we could live without them, but I don't have a strong opinion either way at the moment. It would be helpful to see arguments for having them.

Comment: its strange how few high rep users & even mods on SE seem to be familiar with the idea of a [folksonomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folksonomy) which is highly relevant. the basic idea is that tags are community-discovered/ user-generated content and dont really directly/ definitively determine the applicability of questions, and regulations on their use are not a great or even effective way to steer content, that all would be the tail wagging the dog so to speak. also some flexibility in tag use/ discovery is inherent to all folksonomies and too much rigidity decreases their utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Once again](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/679/why-are-there-tags-for-programming-languages), no. This suggestion has all the hallmarks of “we must do something, this is something, so let's do it”.

If there was no [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag then askers would use some other tag, such as [programming-languages](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages), or [algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), or [complexity](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity) (because the homework exercise is hard, i.e. complex — don't laugh, I've seen it often). Hell, even though we have a [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, [C questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50043/problem-in-combining-elements-in-a-move-2048-program-in-c) [don't always use it](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50241/use-of-reference-from-inside-of-a-function)! It's hard to evaluate because the amount of programming questions we get in a given programming language is heavily dependent on the popularity of the language among askers (mainly CS/programming students), but I don't get the impression that we get, say, more Java ([java](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)) questions than C# (no tag) questions, in proportion with the potential demand. (C# is about as popular as Java on SO, but it's less popular in programming courses, and even more so in CS courses.)

In my experience on Stack Exchange, the argument “there's a tag so this must be on-topic” doesn't come up very often, and when it comes up it's often a post-hoc justification which is obviously invalid if you spend thirty seconds reading the site's scope (e.g. justifying a Windows question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) because “there's a [windows] tag” — I wonder how often [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) gets questions about the Windows operating system in their [windows] tag). Tags are the last thing an akser types, after the title and the body of the question; how many people do you think abandon their question when they don't see an appropriate tag, as opposed to semi-randomly picking a tag just to get the question through? We get a lot of programming homework questions

1. because the askers are in a *computer science* curriculum;
2. because askers come here after getting banned from Stack Overflow for asking too many low-quality questions.

The programming language tags serve a purpose: they characterize questions about that language. The semantics of programming languages is a domain of computer science, it is on-topic here. These tags serve a need. Even if they caused some harm, which I dispute, that would not remove our need for them. If people asking off-topic because of the presence of the tag was a widespread phenomenon, we could try renaming [c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c) to [semantics-of-c](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/semantics-of-c) or some such, but I think that the phenomenon is so negligible that it isn't worth sacrificing clear tag names.

Comment: I disagree that CS semantics questions should be tied to specific languages (usually) but that's not strong enough to disagree with your answer in total. For the record, I don't like that we have these tags but I agree that there is no need for action.