# Burninate tag: pseudocode

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [four questions tagged "pseudocode"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudocode). This question seems to have no value:

- any question that requests an algorithm would be off-topic if it required a specific language, so tagging a "Please give me an algorithm to do X" question with "pseudocode" is redundant;
- the answer to any question *about* pseudocode is "Do whatever you want, as long as it's clear", so the tag has no use there, either.

Burninate?

Comment: Why do we even have that? O.o Hm, maybe it's valid together with [tag:didactics] or [tag:education]? Not that we get lots of _those_...

Comment: Yes. True, burninate (I hope we treat vote up as vote).

Answer (score 9):

## Yes

Burninate the tag! (Feel free to give specific reasons in the comment.)

Please vote on yes/no just by upvoting on the answer you agree with.

Answer (score 3):

## No

Keep the tag because it serves a useful purpose! (Please explain that purpose in a comment or separate answer.)

Please vote on yes/no just by upvoting on the answer you agree with.

Comment: Questions above pseudocode conventions (half the questions in your list) are legitimate (in my view).

Comment: I think this tag would have the same usage as the [tag:C], [tag:C++], [tag:java], [tag:python], etc. That is, more of a heuristic to detect bad posts than an actual tag, with a few questions being on-topic. Given that that has been [decided to be the function](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146) of those tags, it seems natural to extend it to this tag.

Comment: This is very good reason to keep it as honey pot, but how many "not real" tags should be kept? Since the pseudocode is preffered notation here, I think it may confuse people and will result in using it to show there is some kind of pseudocode present (pure conjecture, I have no data about it), the false positives of honey pot will in turn give more work to check it.

Comment: I find the "honeypot" idea very dubious. Also with no data, my suspicion is that finding a tag for questions about X encourages new posters to believe that X is on-topic. The review process already seems fairly efficient at closing down the off-topic questions so I'm not seeing the benefit of having a tag that's effectively "Off-topic questions that will be auto-deleted after 30 days." The meta thread linked by Discrete lizard is probably the place to discuss this, rather than here.